# disable whitespace mode on new buffers

Tags: whitespace-mode

After doing an some emacs packages updates, every time a new file is opened the buffer has whitespace mode turned on. I see red on all the whitespace at the start of lines. I've tried disabling whitespace-mode, but can't change this behavior from happening on every new buffer.

Is there someway to make sure whitespace-mode is disabled on new buffers?

Comment: Turn off `global-whitspace-mode`?  Try  a word search for that function in your packages or user configuration and perhaps you'll find that it has been enabled.

Comment: that has no impact on it. global-whitespace-mode off still opens new buffers with whitespace mode on. There must be something overriding this setting

Comment: Consider typing `M-x describe-mode` and update your question by listing all of the minor-modes that are active in the buffer just after opening it.  If `whitespace-mode` is enabled, there two usual methods:  `(global-whitespace-mode 1)` or `(whitespace-mode 1)`.  If you don't have either one of those somewhere in your setup, then I'm out of ideas.  I suppose there could be a derived-mode like text-mode or prog-mode, which has something like `(whitespace-mode 1)` attached to a derived major-mode hook -- but that is certainly less common.

Comment: In the mode-line, there is usually a capital **WS** for `global-whitespace-mode` and a little **ws** for buffer-local `whitespace-mode`.

Comment: you're right, when first opening a file whitespace is enabled! I'm looking through my init to see if something is enabling it

Comment: New Drew: Your name is going to be extremely confusing on this particular site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prelude's own *prelude-whitespace* was causing the behavior. You can disable it using:

```
M-x customize-group RET prelude
```

Set *Prelude Whitespace* (`prelude-whitespace`) to off/nil (default is on).

---

According to the [prelude docs](https://prelude.emacsredux.com/en/latest/configuration/#disabling-whitespace-mode) you can also set this variable in your configuration:

```
(setq prelude-whitespace nil)
```

Comment: If this resolved your problem, could you please accept your own answer so we can mark it as done, please?

Comment: Seems to still happen. Deleting the emacs cache file fixes it temporarily...

Comment: I'll just accept this, it's still happening but much less than before